# How can I eliminate double login?

Tags: macos, bash

When I login into my Mac OSX a bash shell is configured to automatially open and run a script.

This script requires super user privs and asks for my password again.

Is there a way to eliminate this.  I would prefer to enter my password only once.

Answer (score 2):

Just modify the sudoers file to allow the script to run without a password:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then add the line (with appropriate modifications) to the end of the file:

```
YourUserName ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/script
```

Once you save and exit you'll be able to run `sudo /path/to/your/script` without being prompted for a password.

Comment: `a ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: ~/root/config/bash/login.sh` is giving me an error. My username is in fact just `a` , I verified this using `whoami` and its what my mac sais when I turn it on.

Comment: You need to specify the absolute path to your script, e.g. `/Users/a/root/config/bash/login.sh`

Answer (score 0):

How is the script being launched?

One way to have a script run on startup under superuser would be to create an app with automater, add the run shell script action, type in `sudo sh "path to your script"`, save it, and then add the app to login items under System Preferences -> Accounts -> Login items